# Issue with posting a object in Angular 2 and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

With postman I get the right response with the following json in the body:

```
{
    "cpu": {
        "filters": [
            ]
    }
}
```

In my Angular 2 service I post a request like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { BaseService } from './base.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Cpu } from '../entities/cpu';
import { PostObject } from '../entities/post-object';
import { CPU } from '../datasource/database-data';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CpuService extends BaseService {
    postObject: PostObject;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
      super();
    }

        getCpus(): void {
        this.postObject = new PostObject();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.postObject));
            this.http.post(this.getUrl('/searchCPU'), JSON.stringify(this.postObject))
                .subscribe((result: any) =>
                    console.log(result);
                    return result
                });
        }
}`
```

The PostObject:

```
export class PostObject {
    cpu: {
        filters: string[]
    }
}
```

When I console log my postObject object, it's empty...? Maybe `this.postObject = new PostObject();` is wrong ..?

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Comment: where have you set data in `PostObject`?

Comment: And by "empty" what do you mean? Undefined or simply without data? You need to add collection of strings into filters array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes would need a constructor, if that is what you want to send. I wonder about the use case of sending empty Object, but you could also skip the classes and create an Object manually. This would not be good to maintain though, but could be achieved with the following:

```ts
this.postObject = {cpu:{filters:[]}}
```

And if you want classes you would have two:

```ts
export class PostObject {
    constructor(public cpu: Cpu) {}
}

export class Cpu {
    constructor(public filters: string[]) {}
}
```

and create a new `PostObject` like so:

```ts
this.postObject = new PostObject(new Cpu([]))
```

Both methods achieve what you want, i.e:

```ts
{
    "cpu": {
        "filters": [
            ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want JSON as the post body, set the correct content-type header:

```
this.http.post(this.getUrl('/searchCPU'), JSON.stringify(this.postObject), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```